# Multipart Request com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: android, android-volley, multipart

I have to send a multipart request of the form

file : file , data : {"DocTypeID":1,"DriverID":2}

What I am doing is:

```
MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(ServiceUrls.BASE_URL + ServiceUrls.DOCUMENT_BASE_URL,getHeader(), new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    },file,object){
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            responseCode = response.statusCode;
            handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    responseAction();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 300);
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
```

The code for my MultipartRequest class is as follows

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

private MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
private static final String JSON_PART_NAME = "data";
private final Map<String, String> mHeaders;
private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File mFilePart;
private final JSONObject mJsonObjectPart;
private HttpEntity mHttpEntity;


public MultipartRequest(String url,Map<String, String> headers, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, File file, JSONObject jsonObject)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    mHeaders = headers;
    mListener = listener;
    mFilePart = file;
    mJsonObjectPart=jsonObject;
    mHttpEntity = buildMultipartEntity();
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

private HttpEntity buildMultipartEntity()
{
    builder.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
    builder.addPart(JSON_PART_NAME, new StringBody(mJsonObjectPart.toString(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    return builder.build();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return mHttpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        mHttpEntity.writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}


@Override
public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (mHeaders!=null)?mHeaders:super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response)
{
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

When I am running the code , I am getting the volley.ServerError and I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated. 
I am making the JSONObject correctly.

Comment: Don't ignore `VolleyError error`. Log it and edit your question to include it

Comment: You will get the error code in `onErrorResponse()` its hard to send multipart requests using volley. and finally i switched to retrofit2 and it works well

Comment: @cricket_007 VolleyError is as I told com.android.volley.ServerError

Comment: Okay, then what do the server logs say?

Comment: Actually its working. Sorry. I was passing the incorrect url for a long time without realizing it

Comment: Actually its working. Sorry. I was passing the incorrect url for a long time without realizing it